# Use nth-child css selector with jsf repeat tag

Tags: html, css, jsf, repeat, css-selectors

im trying to make my html page work with JSF, and have stumbled upon a problem, namely, how can I make *nth-child* css selector work with jsf *repeat* tag? Right now for every element that *repeat* tag produces, the first child's css is used.

Here's plain HTML:

```
            <table>
                        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                <td class="costs" >
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>25</li>
                                        <li>25</li>
                                        <li>25</li>
                                        <li>25</li>
                                        <li>25</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            <tbody>
        <table>
```

And CSS:

```
.costs ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/food.png']}");
}

.costs ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/wood.png']}");
}

.costs ul li:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/stone.png']}");
}

.costs ul li:nth-child(4) {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/iron.png']}");
}

.costs ul li:nth-child(5) {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/gold.png']}");
}

.costs ul li:nth-child(6) {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images:icons/time.png']}");
}
```

And here's JSF counterpart:

```
                <h:dataTable>    
             <h:column>
                        <div class="costs" >
                            <ul>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{item.goods}" var="goodType">
                                    <li>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{goodType}" ></h:outputText>                                                   
                                    </li>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </ul>       
                        </div>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `jsf`, but I assume that `<ui:repeat` line is creating some html element and that's why your code is failing.

Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qfGr5/) and you should get on track.

From the example you can see that if `li` is wrapped into `div` it always will be `:first-child` or `:nth-child(1)` in your case.

So your code should work with this `CSS`:

```
.costs ul div:nth-child(1) li {
    background: red;
}
```

Where div is html element created of `<ui:repeat`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qfGr5/1/)

Comment: ui:repeat won't generate any extra html tags, it's a loop.

Comment: That was the only logical explanation.